# Cannot Access Inner Nodes of JSON

Tags: c#, json.net

I am trying to get the inner nodes of my JSON.

In particular, I am trying to get the values within "A", and "B".

However, my JSON starts with "Things", then it goes to "A" and "B".

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace Rextester
{
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        string json = "{\"Things\":[{\"A\":\"one\",\"B\":\"two\",\"C\":\"three\",\"D\":\"four\",\"E\":\"five\", \"F\":\"six\"},\"G\":\"seven\"}]}";

        var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json).First.First;
        Console.WriteLine(jsonObj["Things"]);
    }

    public class Account
    {
        public string A
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string B
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: your JSON is not valid

Comment: ...it has 3 closing braces and 2 opening braces.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is invalid assuming the valid JSON:

```
{
  "Things": [{
      "A": "one",
      "B": "two",
      "C": "three",
      "D": "four",
      "E": "five",
      "F": "six" },
  {"G": "seven"}]
}
```

You need to define class for JSON using key,value pairs as follows:

```
public class Myclass
{
    public Dictionary<string, string>[] Things { get; set; }    
}
```

Then you are good to go :

```
string json = "{\"Things\":[{\"A\":\"one\",\"B\":\"two\",\"C\":\"three\",\"D\":\"four\",\"E\":\"five\", \"F\":\"six\"},{\"G\":\"seven\"}]}";

var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Myclass>(json);
Console.WriteLine(jsonObj.Things[0]["A"]);
Console.WriteLine(jsonObj.Things[0]["B"]);
```

Output :

```
one
two
```

Answer (score 0):

To help generate your classes for JSON, you can use this website http://json2csharp.com/
Really useful when you have big JSON. It will also validate your json.